# Infinitely pairs of positive integers such that $1+2+\cdots+k = (k+1)+(k+2)+\cdots+N$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that there are infinitely many pairs $(k,N)$ of positive integers such that $1+2+\cdots+k = (k+1)+(k+2)+\cdots+N$.

I thought of transforming this into a Pell equation, but I didn't see a way of doing that. Should we show that if the equation is true for some $(k,N)$ it is also true for another?

Comment: @lulu In that question I asked about a solution. In this one I ask for a solution.

Comment: The Pell equation idea works well.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you explain how to do it?

Comment: @user19405892: Maybe. It reduces to $x^2-2y^2=2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Suppose that $(k,N)$ is a solution. Then we have $$1+2+\cdots+k = \dfrac{k(k+1)}{2}= (k+1)+(k+2)+\cdots+N = \dfrac{(N-k)(N+k+1)}{2},$$ which means $2k(k+1) = N(N+1)$. This can be transformed into the negative Pell equation $(2N+1)^{2}-2(2k+1)^{2}=-1$. This was the answer given in the other linked question, but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: From a solution you get another by "multiplying" by a fundamental solution of the Pellian with right-hand side $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, because the solution respect to, for example to $k$ is:
$$k=N-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{(8N^2+1)},$$ excluding the negative ones,
you can get infinite solutions. Given $N$ you can get $k$

Comment: Which equation did you solve to get that?

Comment: @user19405892: the equation yoy have written in the question.

Comment: I get $k = -\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 N^2+2 N+1}$.

Comment: @user19405892: the first sum is $\dfrac{1}{2}(k^2+k)$. The second one is: $kN+\dfrac{1}{2}(N^2+N)$

Comment: We have $\dfrac{k(k+1)}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2}(k^2+k)$ and $\dfrac{(N-k)(N+k+1)}{2} = \dfrac{N^2+N-k-k^2}{2}$.

Comment: @user19405892: you have to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^N(k+n)$

Comment: That's not correct. It goes up to $N$, not $k+N$.

Answer (score 0):

$$1+2+\cdots+k = (k+1)+(k+2)+\cdots+N$$
you can find the sums of two sides and you will get a second degree equation solve it and you get: $$k=\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2N^2+2N+1}$$

use this "Maple" instructions you get the solution:

> $f:=k->\sum_{i=0}^{k}i-\sum_{j=k+1}^{N}j$:
>
> $solve\left(f(k)=0,k\right)$;